# how to take combined string and num as filename in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to use a combined string and num as a file name, like that:

```
for im_num = 1:10
    im_name = sprintf('bottle crate/bottle_crate_%d.png',im_num); 
    file_num =  sprintf('f%d',im_num); 
    file_num = imread(im_name);
end
```

I can use combined string as file path, but the filename, I want to change from f1, f2 to f10 but it didn't work, how to change it?

Comment: Try running the loop to see if you can just print the file name (display `im_name` for each iteration). Seems like the `sprintf` is working fine, you may have the wrong path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there is no problem in im_name. for example, I use "  im_name = sprintf('bottle crate/bottle_crate_%d.png',1);   f1 = imread(im_name); imshow(f1) "  but I want to save f1,f2....f10 directly, so the main problem is on the file_num

Comment: You want to rename the files from `bottle_crate_1.png` to `f1`?

Comment: @HS-nebula yes, in the loop, I want to f1 =imread(bottle_crate_1.png), f2 =imread(bottle_crate_2.png), f3 =imread(bottle_crate_3.png),....

Comment: You can't dynamically create variables, like `f1`, `f2`, etc. Instead, you should save the results to a cell array or perform the rest of your operations in the loop for each file.

Comment: you actually can.... no need to do that , but you can if you want to

Comment: Why not simply `f(im_num) = imread(im_name);`? There is no need to create dynamic variable names for something like this. There is always a simple solution that is easier to maintain and more performant.